# What would cause an HP LaserJet P2015 to stop printing despite being "Ready" and online on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, printer

My HP P2015 printer has worked flawlessly for a few years. Lately, I can print to it sometimes and it prints fine, from my Windows 7 computer, but often it locks up, not willing to print jobs that end up queued up in the spooler.

Windows 7 reports the printer is online and ready. The top job in the queue claims that it is "Printing". The green light on the printer that indicates it is ready is on (solid, not flashing).

Toggling the printer off and then back on will get it printing again. When toggle the power off and on, Windows plays the sound of a device being disconnected and then reconnected.

Weird because it was all working fine in this very configuration for years, so I suspect perhaps a recent windows update that may have introduced this problem?

I've reseated the USB connections on both ends a couple of times as well.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port on the PC? This can sometimes reset the driver. Also, have you tried a different computer (not so easy I know)?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the printer drivers?

Comment: I have upgraded the drivers and I'm getting the same thing.

I haven't switched ports, but I will try that.

No, I haven't tried switching computers, and you're right, it's not so easy.  ;-)

Comment: Switched USB ports. It's doing the same thing. Also tried restarting the Print Spooler service. Doesn't help. Windows 7 seems to think that the printer is connected and that it's actually printing to the printer. The printer has a solid green light indicating that it's in the ready state. However, nothing is going through. It's only when I power the printer off and then back on that my spooled jobs start printing.